# Selecionar primeiro registro dentro de uma segmentação no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte tabela exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A consulta pede que eu mostre quais alunos ingressaram primeiro em cada curso. Eu consigo dizer qual aluno ingressou primeiro na universidade, usando a função `top(1)`, mas como eu posso fazer isso para cada curso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize a função ROW NUMBER, ela exibira uma ordenação conforme uma "quebra" no caso, por código do curso.

```
    SELECT * 
        FROM 
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_curso ORDER BY data_ingresso ) as ROW_NUM
, *
         FROM NOME_TABELA
        ) TB_AUX
    WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Comment: Funcionou, só precisei tirar o desc, pois a questão queria o aluno que entrou primeiro, logo, o aluno que a data de ingresso fosse a menor, então a ordenação deve ser de ordem crescente

Comment: Tem razão, o Desc inverte a ordenação. vou editar a resposta

Answer (score 10):

`CTE` com `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_curso ORDER BY data_ingresso) AS row
   FROM ALUNOS
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE row= 1
```

`SubQuery` Correlacionada:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM
  (SELECT ALUNOS.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_curso
                              ORDER BY data_ingresso) AS linha
   FROM ALUNOS) l
WHERE l.linha = 1;
```

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a193/2)

## Update

Hoje aprendi um jeito diferente de se fazer uma consulta que irá gerar  o mesmo resultado.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALUNOS
INNER JOIN(SELECT codigo_curso, MIN(data_ingresso) data_ingresso
    FROM ALUNOS
    GROUP BY codigo_curso) A
ON ALUNOS.codigo_curso = A.codigo_curso
AND ALUNOS.data_ingresso = A.data_ingresso
```

- Pegue a menor `data_ingresso` agrupado pelo `codigo_curso`
- Faça um `JOIN` com esse resultado.

*Você quis dizer ao SQL:*

> Retorne os alunos que se ingressaram primeiro a um determinado curso.

- ***PARTITION BY value_expression*** - `value_expression` especifica a coluna pela qual o conjunto de resultados é particionado.
- ***Order_by_clause*** - Determina as ordens em que as linhas serão atribuídas.

*`Row Number`* em poucas palavras irá atribuir uma ordem para suas linhas.

## Leituras Recomendadas:

- <sub>[O que é ROW_NUMBER?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233207/o-que-%C3%A9-row-number)</sub>
- <sub>[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)</sub>

Comment: Explicou com ótimas palavras o que é o `particion by`.

Answer (score 7):

Interessante a pergunta. Fui pesquisar e encontrei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841644/4551469):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codigo_curso ORDER BY data_ingresso DESC) AS rn
   FROM tusu
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Só usei para testes, mas parece funcionar para o que você precisa.