# O que é ROW_NUMBER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, terminologia

O que é `ROW_NUMBER` usado no `sql server`?

Como e onde devemos utiliza-lo?

Tem um exemplo simples de uso ?

Comment: [Selecionar primeiro registro dentro de uma segmentação no SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233166/selecionar-primeiro-registro-dentro-de-uma-segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-sql-server/233178#233178) eu fiz uma edição detalhando a resposta aqui.

Comment: @Marconi, não explicar detalhadamente a função na sua resposta.

Comment: Entendi, vou ver se consigo bolar uma resposta bem esclarecida aqui se alguém não postar antes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) é uma [função não-determinística](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions) que retorna um número sequencial - e potencialmente volátil - calculado enquanto (e sempre que) a *query* é executada e serve para enumerar os resultados da execução desta *query*.

Sempre que usar a função `ROW_NUMBER` é necessário usar a cláusula [**`OVER()`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) com um `ORDER BY`. Não necessariamente este `ORDER BY` precisa ser a ordenação dos dados, ele apenas determina como serão gerados os números pela função `ROW_NUMBER` (e é por isso que a cláusula é obrigatória).

Na clausula `OVER` também é possível usar uma cláusula `PARTITION BY`, ela definirá quando a "contagem" de `ROW_NUMBER` deve reiniciar.

Por exemplo, eis uma *query* normal com ordenação pelo campo `name`.

```
SELECT 
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id < 5
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

O resultado seria algo como:

```
name      recovery_model_desc
----------------------------
master    SIMPLE
model     FULL
msdb      SIMPLE
tempdb    SIMPLE
```

E aqui a mesma *query* usando `ROW_NUMBER()`. Note que a ordenação foi movida para dentro do `OVER()`.

O resultado seria:

```
Row#    name     recovery_model_desc
1       master   SIMPLE
2       model    FULL
3       msdb     SIMPLE
4       tempdb   SIMPLE
```

Um exemplo usando uma ordenação diferente para os dados e para a geração dos valores de `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS Row#,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id < 5
Order By Name Desc;
```

Saída:

```
Row#    name     recovery_model_desc
4       tempdb   SIMPLE
3       msdb     SIMPLE    
2       model    FULL
1       master   SIMPLE
```

E um exemplo usando o `PARTITION BY recovery_model_desc`.

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY recovery_model_desc ORDER BY name ASC) 
    AS Row#,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id < 5;
```

A saída seria assim:

```
Row#    name     recovery_model_desc
1       model    FULL
1       master   SIMPLE
2       msdb     SIMPLE
3       tempdb   SIMPLE
```

<sub>Os exemplos foram copiados da [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql).</sub>

[Veja mais na documentação oficial do SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql).

Answer (score 11):

**ROW_NUMBER**

A função ROW_NUMBER retorna o número sequencial de uma linha dentro de uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, começando em 1 para a primeira linha em cada partição.

**ROW_NUMBER e RANK**

ROW_NUMBER e RANK são semelhantes. ROW_NUMBER numerará todas as linhas sequencialmente (por exemplo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). RANK fornece o mesmo valor numérico para registros de mesma posição (por exemplo, **1, 2, 2, 4, 5**). Estes valores são calculados em memória e não estão fisicamente nas tabelas.

**SINTAXE**

```
ROW_NUMBER ( )   
OVER ( [ PARTITION BY value_expression , ... [ n ] ] order_by_clause )
```

**PARTITION BY value_expression**
Divide o conjunto de resultados produzido pela cláusula FROM em partições às quais a função ROW_NUMBER é aplicada. Value_expression especifica a coluna pela qual o conjunto de resultados é particionado. Se PARTITION BY não for especificado, a função trata todas as linhas do conjunto de resultados da consulta como um único grupo.

**Order_by_clause**
A cláusula ORDER BY determina a seqüência em que as linhas são atribuídas seu ROW_NUMBER exclusivo dentro de uma partição especificada. É necessário. Para obter mais informações, consulte a Cláusula Over Over

**Exemplo 1**

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY recovery_model_desc ORDER BY name ASC) 
    AS Row#,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id < 5;
```

**Exemplo 2**

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT FirstName, LastName, TerritoryName, ROUND(SalesYTD,2,1),  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TerritoryName ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) 
  AS Row  
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson  
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0  
ORDER BY TerritoryName;
```

Referência: Microsoft Docs documentation [ROW_NUMBER function](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

Answer (score 5):

### O que é

ROW_NUMBER é uma função do SQL Server usada para **numeração de registros**.

---

### A sintaxe

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CampoA ORDER BY CampoB)
```

---

### Detalhe

```
ROW_NUMBER() --Obrigatório
```

Responsável por atribuir **um número** a **um registro**.

```
OVER() --Obrigatório
```

É onde se define **como** os registro serão numerados.

```
ORDER BY --Obrigatório
```

Ordena algum campo de forma acendente `ASC` ou descendente `DESC` antes de aplicar a numeração.

```
PARTITION BY --Opcional
```

**Agrupa os valores** de algum campo e faz **uma numeração separada pra cada grupo**

---

### Tabela de exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM PESSOAS
```

Resultado:

```
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦ID ¦NOME             ¦GENERO ¦CIDADE      |
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦1  ¦DENIS            ¦M      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦2  ¦JULIANA          ¦F      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦3  ¦LUCAS            ¦M      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦4  ¦MÁRCIA           ¦F      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦5  ¦RODRIGO          ¦M      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦6  ¦MARIANA          ¦F      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦7  ¦OTÁVIO           ¦M      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+---+-----------------+-------+------------+
```

Esta é a tabela que será usada como exemplo.

---

### Exemplo 1

`ROW_NUMBER()` com `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CIDADE DESC) AS NUMERACAO,
NOME, GENERO, CIDADE 
FROM PESSOAS
```

Resultado:

```
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦NUMERACAO ¦NOME             ¦GENERO ¦CIDADE      |
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦1         ¦DENIS            ¦M      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦2         ¦MÁRCIA           ¦F      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦3         ¦OTÁVIO           ¦M      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦4         ¦RODRIGO          ¦M      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦5         ¦MARIANA          ¦F      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦6         ¦JULIANA          ¦F      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦7         ¦LUCAS            ¦M      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
```

Neste caso os resultados da tabela são ordenados por **CIDADE** em ordem **decrescente**, em seguida **os registros são numerados**.

---

### Exemplo 2

`ROW_NUMBER()` com `ORDER BY` e `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GENERO ORDER BY CIDADE DESC) AS NUMERACAO,
NOME, GENERO, CIDADE 
FROM PESSOAS
```

Resultado:

```
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦NUMERACAO ¦NOME             ¦GENERO ¦CIDADE      |
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦1         ¦MÁRCIA           ¦F      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦2         ¦JULIANA          ¦F      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦3         ¦MARIANA          ¦F      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦1         ¦OTÁVIO           ¦M      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦2         ¦DENIS            ¦M      ¦SÃO PAULO   ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦3         ¦LUCAS            ¦M      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
¦4         ¦RODRIGO          ¦M      ¦CAMPINAS    ¦
+----------+-----------------+-------+------------+
```

Neste outro caso o `PARTITION BY` **agrupa** os resultados **por GENERO**, em seguida o `ORDER BY` **ordena** os registros **de cada grupo** por **CIDADE**, em ordem **decrescente**. Finalmente **os registros de cada grupo são numerados**.

Referência:

> [Row Number Function in SQL Server - C# Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/row-number-function-in-sql-server/)