# Consultas de linhas ímpares SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Preciso criar script de consulta que retorne da tabela abaixo somente as suas linhas ímpares, ordenadas de forma ascendente:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (coluna1 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('Anthony'),('Miguel'),('Benjamin'),('Lucca'),('Enzo'),('Martim'), ('Noah'),('Gael'),('Henrique'),('Heitor'),('Nícolas'),('Bernardo'), ('Filipe'),('Arthur'),('Apolo'),('José'),('João'),('Antônio'), ('Vicente'),('Alice'),('Luna'),('Valentina'),('Isabela'),('Larissa' ), ('Laura'),('Antonella'),('Victoria'),('Julia'),('Manuela'),('Ana'), ('Camila'),('Beatriz'),('Elisa'),('Sophia'),('Mayara'),('Maria')
```

Observação: Não posso alterar o script acima criando outro campo como id.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233207/o-que-%C3%A9-row-number) para enumerar as linhas, divida a linha por `2` em que o resto dessa divisão seja `1`.  O operador `%`(MOD) vai ser necessário nesse caso.

Repare que utilizei uma `subConsulta` não-correlacionada, ou seja, uma `subConsulta` em que o resultado externo dependente do resultado interno.

Um exemplo bem parecido com o seu;

```
CREATE TABLE LINHASIMPARES (TEXTO VARCHAR(10) );


INSERT INTO LINHASIMPARES (TEXTO)
VALUES('MARCONI'),('MAGNO'), ('ALEX');


SELECT L.TEXTO,
       L.LINHA
FROM
  (SELECT TEXTO,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                            ORDER BY TEXTO ASC) AS LINHA
   FROM LINHASIMPARES) L
WHERE L.LINHA % 2 = 1;
```

## [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9df8b/2)