# Ajuda com distinct

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, select

Tenho a seguinte consulta sql:

`select nome, data, situacao from cadastro`

O resultado é assim:

```
MARIA   01/01/2018  0
MARIA   15/01/2018  1
GISELE  15/01/2018  0
CICERA  08/01/2018  1
ANTONIA 20/01/2018  0
ANTONIA 15/01/2018  1
```

Preciso fazer um distinct pelo nome:

`select distinct(nome), data, situacao from cadastro group by data, situacao`

O problema é que ele não faz o distinct porque as datas são diferentes, porém, eu preciso que, quando a paciente tenha duas fichas (situação 0 e 1), seja listada apenas a ficha com situação = 1.

Nesse caso, deveria gerar o resultado assim:

```
MARIA   15/01/2018  1
GISELE  15/01/2018  0
CICERA  08/01/2018  1
ANTONIA 15/01/2018  1
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: pode ter mais siturações? 2,3,4 ?  pode o paciente ter duas fichas com situação 1 e datas diferentes ?

Comment: não, só 0 e 1 mesmo @RovannLinhalis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim seu `distinct` não irá funcionar pelo fato de você está adicionando a `data` no resultado.

Sugiro você enumerar suas linhas com a função `ROW_NUMBER` segmentando pelo nome e ordenando a situação de modo decrescente(*do maior para o menor*).

```
SELECT l.*
FROM
  (SELECT Cadastro.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nome
                              ORDER BY situacao desc) AS linha
   FROM Cadastro) l
WHERE LINHA = 1;
```

## [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5d92/8)

**ROW_NUMBER**

> Definem a saída de um resultado de números. Mais especificamente,
>   retorna o número sequencial`(1,2,3,4...)` de uma linha dentro de uma partição de um
>   conjunto de resultados, começando em 1 para a primeira linha em cada
>   partição.

Respondendo ao seu comentário:

`WHERE LINHA = 1` será a primeira linha sequencial. Caso necessite trocar para pegar as linhas com `situacao = 0`, basta trocar para `WHERE LINHA = 2`.

**PARTITION BY value_expression**

Divide o conjunto de resultados produzido pelo FROM cláusula em partições às quais a função `ROW_NUMBER` é aplicada. value_expression Especifica a coluna pela qual o conjunto de resultados é particionado. Se `PARTITION BY` não for especificado, a função tratará todas as linhas do conjunto como um único grupo de resultados de consulta.

Algumas respostas parecidas:

- [Selecionar primeiro registro dentro de uma segmentação no SQL
  Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233166/selecionar-primeiro-registro-dentro-de-uma-segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-sql-server/233178#233178)
- [Consultas de linhas ímpares SQL SERVER](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257689/consultas-de-linhas-%C3%ADmpares-sql-server/257694#257694)

Veja mais na documentação:

## [PostgreSQL ROW_NUMBER function](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/)

Comment: funcionou, porém eu não entendi seu código. pode me explicar? principalmente o `over partition by`? e porque o `row_number` pega apenas as linhas com situacao = 1?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo resposta editada.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz de uma forma não simplificada, mas resolve teu problema,
Tive que adicionar um ID para pegar os registors corretos no where se você tiver outro idenficador a logica é a mesma

```
select c.nome, c.data, c.situacao 
    from cadastro c 
    where c.id in (select max(cs.id)
                    from cadastro cs where cs.situacao = 1
                    group by cs.nome) 
        or (c.situacao = 0 and 
                c.nome not in (select css.nome
                            from cadastro css where css.situacao = 1
                            group by css.nome))
```

este código esta disponivel no SQL [snippet](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6eec9/14)

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo agrupando apenas pelo `nome`, e usando `max(situacao)`, depois utilizo essa tabela com join no select para buscar os outros dados. Veja:

```
select
    y.nome,
    x.data,
    y.situacao
from tabela x
inner join (
            select
              t.nome,
              max(t.situacao) as situacao
            from tabela t
            group by t.nome) y on y.nome = x.nome and y.situacao = x.situacao
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/84343/7

Resultado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a mesma lógica de `MAX()` e `Group By` fiz uma outra alternativa de solução com `subselect`:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(C1.nome)
  , (
    SELECT c2.data 
    FROM Cadastro AS c2 
    WHERE c2.situacao = MAX(C1.situacao)
    AND c2.Nome = C1.Nome
  )
  , MAX(C1.situacao)
FROM 
  Cadastro AS C1
GROUP BY C1.Nome
```

Exemplo online:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/13d5b/1)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]