# Trazer a primeira linha com base em uma data em SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mais um desafio parou em minhas mãos. Preciso de ajuda em minha consulta.

**O que eu preciso:**

Quero saber quais são as pessoas que tiveram lançamentos de contas em determinado dia, onde preciso exibir o valor e a situação desse dia.

Sendo assim, eu tenho duas tabelas, uma que tenho o laçamento da pessoa e outra que eu tenho os valores e a situação.

**Tabela e dados**

Essa tabela é um histórico que fica armazenando informações de acordo com as modificações, não necessariamente ocorrem todos os dias.

*Tabela HistPessoa*

```
PessoaId | Situacao | DataInsert | Valor
  999    |   Ativo  | 2018-01-10 | 1111
  999    |   Ativo  | 2018-01-12 | 2222
  999    |   Ativo  | 2018-01-13 | 3333
  999    |   Inativo| 2018-01-18 | 4444
  999    |   Ativo  | 2018-01-20 | 5555
  999    |   Inativo| 2018-01-22 | 5555
  999    |   Ativo  | 2018-01-25 | 6666
```

*Tabela Lancamento*

```
PessoaId | LacamentoId | DataLancamento | Descrocao
   999   |    0001     |  2018-01-17    | Lacamento 1
   999   |    0002     |  2018-01-25    | Lacamento 2
   999   |    0003     |  2018-01-24    | Em divida com o sistema, liberação negada
   999   |    0002     |  2018-01-25    | Lacamento 2 estornado
```

**Observações gerais:**
A tabela HistPessoa mantem um hostórico toda vêz que algum `valor` ou `situação` é alterado. Através do data de lançamento eu preciso informa a situação e o valor da pessoa no dia do lançamento.

**Exemplo**: No dia  17 de janeiro de 2018 a pessoa 999 estava em situação *Ativo* com valor de *3333*. E no dia 25 de janeiro de 2018 a pessoa 999 estava com situação *Ativo* com valor de *6666*

No lançamento 0001 a `DataLancamento (2018-01-17)` não existe na tabela `HistPessoa`, nesse caso devo pegar a `DataInsert` anterior da `DataLacamento` mais próxima que seria a data `2018-01-13`

`HistPessoa` tem armazenado histórico de longa data, é uma tabela bem grande. Seria interessante ter uma otimização.

**Resultado esperado**

```
PessoaId | LacamentoId | DataLacamento | Situacao | Valor
   999   |   0001      |  2018-01-17   |  Ativo   | 3333
   999   |   0002      |  2018-01-25   |  Ativo   | 6666
```

**O que eu fiz até agora**

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PessoaId ORDER BY DataInsert DESC) AS NUM,
         PessoaId,
         valor,
         Situacao
         FROM HistPessoa
         ORDER BY DataInsert DESC
```

Essa consulta ordena em ordem decrescente, mas não filtra por data sendo assim, pega a ultima data insedira na tabela `HistPessoa`.

**Extra**
Montei algo mais completo baseado na minha solução real. Onde eu parto pelo `Lancamento` em busca dos demais dados.
Segue o link no SQL Fiddle mais completo. [AQUI](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0db47/10)

Alguma dica? Ou possível solução?

Talvez com CTE ou Gaps And Island?

Comment: Coloca um exemplo do resultado esperado

Comment: `SELECT * FROM HistPessoa WHERE PessoaId = @Lancamento_PessoaId AND DataInsert <= @Lancamento_DataLancamento ORDER BY DataInsert DESC` ? (você inseriria os valores desejados onde está '@Lancamento_') Ou você quer o resultado das duas tabelas juntos?

Comment: @MarlonTiedt Adicionei. Para os dois tipos de Lançamentos

Comment: @PedroGaspar-LoboFX Eu editei a pergunta e coloquei os resultados esperados. Preciso fazer um join entre as tabelas

Comment: Entendi muito bem sua dúvida não, mas se reformular posso te ajudar. Acho que as **observações** está um pouco confusa de entender.

Comment: @Marconi Realmente tava ruim. Consegue entender agora?

Comment: @EmanuelF olha minha resposta!

Comment: @Marconi Editei novamente, adicionei o link para um novo SQL Fiddle baseado no que tu montou.

Comment: @EmanuelF já pesquisei sobre e CTE vai ter o mesmo processamento de uma subconsulta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73888/discussion-between-marconi-and-emanuelf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE HISTPESSOA(
 PessoaId int,
 Situacao varchar(10),
 DataInsert date,
 Valor int
);

INSERT INTO HISTPESSOA(PessoaId,Situacao,DataInsert,Valor) values
(999,'Ativo','2018-01-10',1111),
(999,'Ativo','2018-01-12',2222),
(999,'Ativo','2018-01-13',3333),
(999,'Inativo','2018-01-18',4444),
(999,'Ativo','2018-01-20',5555),
(999,'Inativo','2018-01-22',5555),
(999,'Ativo','2018-01-25',6666);


CREATE TABLE LANCAMENTO(
 PessoaId int,
 LacamentoId int,
 DataLancamento date
);
INSERT INTO LANCAMENTO(PessoaId,LacamentoId,DataLancamento) values
(999,0001,'2018-01-17'),
(999,0002,'2018-01-25');
```

## Query:

```
SELECT l.*
    FROM
      (SELECT HP.PessoaId,
              L.LacamentoId,
              L.DataLancamento,
              HP.Valor,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY L.LacamentoId
                                 ORDER BY DataInsert DESC) AS linha
       FROM HISTPESSOA HP
       INNER JOIN LANCAMENTO L ON HP.PessoaId = L.PessoaId
       WHERE HP.DataInsert <= L.DataLancamento) l
    WHERE l.linha = 1;
```

## Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Explicação:

- Use `ROW_NUMBER` para enumerar suas linhas
- Segmente pela coluna `LacamentoId`.
- Ordene de forma descendente a coluna `DataInsert`.
- Pegue a primeira linha, pois será a linha anterior que deseja!

Eu cheguei há esse resultado utilizando como base essa outra resposta minha:
[Selecionar primeiro registro dentro de uma segmentação no SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233166/selecionar-primeiro-registro-dentro-de-uma-segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-sql-server/233178#233178)

Comment: `top 1` com ordenação não resolveria também?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que teria que ser assim msm, pelo que entendi sim. Alguma sugestão de melhoria?

Comment: não tenho certeza. Eu iria testar desse jeito que eu falei, com `top`, mas não tenho certeza se daria certo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado na verdade isso é meio que um `Group by` com top 1. Ele quer pegar o menor registro antes da última DataLancamento através de um IDLancamento.

Comment: Eu acho o `ROW_NUMBER` muito prolixo, sem falar que eu tenho dificuldades de entendê-lo, por isso fujo dele

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado na resposta coloquei um link de outra resposta, lá está mais fácil de entender, mas ele tem que dá uma parada msm pra entender como funciona direitinho.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil usar `limit 1` no final?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam `limit 1` é do Mysql, no Mssql é `top 1`, mas isso vai trazer só 1 registro, não vai dá certo!

Comment: @Marconi o resultado é o esperado. O problema que percebi, é que a tabela Lancamento tem mais registros para o mesmo lançamento com a mesma data. Usando sua solução. Ainda não consegui colocar essa solução em meu contexto real. Não encontrei a forma de explicar, deixa eu analisar melhor. Até o momento, me ajudou a pensar uma forma diferente.

Comment: @EmanuelF se editar sua pergunta com possiveis problemas, altero a consulta pra te ajudar.

Comment: @Marconi Sim, pretendo fazer isso. (Ajudar vocês a me ajudarem). O problema, também esta na otimização, pois o `HistPessoa` tem vários registros e a consulta da forma que tu mostrou, vai enumerar todos os registro a partir da `DataLancamento`.

Comment: @EmanuelF entendi, edita ai cara, vamos ver no que dá pra te ajudar :)