# Trazer apenas um produto por filial no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Bom dia preciso trazer apenas um produto por filial, porém na minha tabela tenho varias vezes o mesmo produto apenas mudando a data, gostaria de pegar o produto da ultima data.

O que eu tenho:

```
SELECT ID, CODFIL, DT, COLUNAVARIANTE FROM X;
```

Resultado:

> ```
> ID  CODFIL    DT    COLUNAVARIANTE
> 1    1       XXXXX        X
> 1    1       YYYYY        Y
> 1    2       XXXXX        X
> 1    3       XXXXX
> ```

O que eu eu preciso

> ```
> ID  CODFIL     DT   COLUNAVARIANTE
> 1    1       XXXXX       X
> 1    2       XXXXX       X
> 1    3       XXXXX       X
> ```

Comment: Você precisa disto: #[Selecionar primeiro registro dentro de uma segmentação no SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233166/selecionar-primeiro-registro-dentro-de-uma-segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-sql-server/233178#233178) Veja funcionaodo: #[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/310ae/1)

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha resposta!

Comment: Exelente @Marconi !!

Comment: Excelente!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: de nada, dá uma lida na pergunta que linkei sobre. Tenho uma resposta lá que tem 3 maneiras de se fazer isto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consulta abaixo deve trazer o que precisa:

```
SELECT ID, CODFIL, max(DT)
FROM X
GROUP BY ID, CODFIL
```

Assim, você terá apenas a maior data referente a cada produto retornado.

Comment: Sim, de fato, perdão pelo meu  erro mas eu não havia colocado a coluna variante no select "SELECT ID, CODFIL, DT, COLUNAVARIANTE FROM X; " nesse caso colocar o max não vai me atender