# Select com group by duplo

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by, count

Em MySQL tenho uma tabela chamada **contato_status**:

```
id | id_contato | detalhamento_id
1  |     1      |       2
2  |     1      |       3
3  |     2      |       4
4  |     2      |       2
5  |     2      |       1
6  |     3      |       2 
7  |     4      |       4
8  |     5      |       4
```

Nela é gravada todos os contatos de atendimento do site, e também sempre que um status é modificado (para histórico). O que preciso agora é listar o total dos detalhamento_id de cada tipo. Consegui com GROUP BY sem problemas. Mas não é o correto. Pois ele pega também os cadastros duplicados (se um usuário tem o status modificado). Então precisaria pegar apenas o detalhamento_id de cada usuário, mas o último, com o ID maior. O que preciso que seja mostrado é isso:

```
detalhamento 1 - 1 ocorrência
detalhamento 2 - 1 ocorrência
detalhamento 3 - 1 ocorrência
detalhamento 4 - 2 ocorrência
```

Como fazer?

Comment: Acho que essa questão e resposta pode te ajudar. Dá uma olhada lá: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233166/selecionar-primeiro-registro-dentro-de-uma-segmenta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-sql-server/233176#233176

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jeito mais simples (talvez não seja o mais elegante) é fazer isso com uma subquery, desta forma:

```
Select contato_status.detalhamento_id, count(*) ocorrencias 
From contato_status 
Inner Join (Select id_contato ,MAX(id) id 
            From contato_status 
            Group By id_contato) NovaTabela
    on contato_status.id = NovaTabela.id 
Group By contato_status.detalhamento_id;
```

Eu adicionei um [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37ba89/2) para ver o funcionamento da query.

Como funciona:

1. A subquery cria cria uma "tabela virtual" (eu prefiro usar o termo conjunto, "set" em inglês), apelidada NovaTabela, com o id_contato e o máximo id. Você pode observar o resultado aqui: [SubQuery isolada](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37ba89/3)
2. Agora é fazer a junção (join) do conjunto com a tabela principal usado o ID como critério desta, agrupando por detalhamento_id e fazendo a contagem.

Como você pode observar, o  resultado obtido é:

```
detalhamento 1 - 1 ocorrência (para o contato_id 2)
detalhamento 2 - 1 ocorrência (para o contato_id 3)
detalhamento 3 - 1 ocorrência (para o contato_id 1)
detalhamento 4 - 2 ocorrências (para os contato_id 4 e 5)
```

Comment: O que seria essa NovaTabela?

Comment: Um alias (apelido) para a subquery. Entenda como uma "tabela" virtual, ou view se preferir.